# I need to get text from 2 different span tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get these values from the following code, the text in span under Developer and Genres

```
<div _ngcontent-sc18="" class="col-xl-6">
  <!-- -->
  <p _ngcontent-sc18="" class="mb-2">
    <strong _ngcontent-sc18="">
     Developer:
    </strong>
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-sc18="">
     Capy Games
  </span>
  </p>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <p _ngcontent-sc18="" class="mb-2">
    <strong _ngcontent-sc18="">
     Genres:
    </strong>
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-sc18="">
     Action,
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-sc18="">
     Platformer
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm able to pull the values fine if there is only one Genre, but if there are two, I can only figure out how to pull the first one. This is what I have so far

```
for y in gamesoup.find_all('p', class_= 'mb-2'):
    if y.strong.text == "Developer: ":
        devs.append(y.span.text)
    if "Genre" in y.strong.text:
        genres.append(y.span.text)
```

What can I do to pull both of the values under Genre?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_all('span')` inside `if` statement of Genre.

```
for y in gamesoup.find_all('p', class_= 'mb-2'):
    if y.strong.text == "Developer: ":
        devs.append(y.span.text)
    if "Genre" in y.strong.text:
        for genre in y.find_all('span'):
            genres.append(genre.text)
```

Comment: I would have sworn I tried that but I guess I didn't, thank you!